# How to change a sprite via script at runtime when using an animator?

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, sprites

I am making a simple 2D shooter.

I have my character's body and head as different objects, as I want him to look up/down regardless of the movement.
So, I basically use the following script:

```
public class PlayerHead : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayerHead instance;
    public SpriteRenderer theSR;
    public Sprite netural, down, up;

    private void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        
    }
    public void Up()
    {
        theSR.sprite = up;
    }

    public void Down()
    {
        theSR.sprite = down;
    }

    public void Netural()
    {
        theSR.sprite = netural;
    }

}
```

However, the head is also used in the player animations:

[image]

This is because head must move with the body during the idle animation (breathing and moving up&down slowly).

I suspect that because of this animation, the sprite of the head is somehow fixed. It does not change in runtime even though I change it manually inside Unity.

How can I make the Animator let me change the sprite?

Comment: Are you looking for [sprite animation re-skinning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMCLWt1DuqI&t=19m20s)?

Comment: @DMGregory Yup! I needed to use the LateUpdate as the Head object is always updated during the animation.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, would you like to post your solution as an Answer below?

Comment: You solved my problem :) I wouldn't want to take credit for your solution.

Comment: You'd be doing me a favour. I've never actually done this, so you have working code that you've tested - I don't. So it would take me more time to write a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [DM Gregory's comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/184036/does-the-animator-prevent-changing-the-sprite-during-runtime?noredirect=1#comment329931_184036), I have understood and solved the issue.

Since I am using the Head object in animator, the sprite is updated in every frame. Therefore, even I change it in one frame, it goes back to default in the next one.

This is the right way to do it:

```
public class PlayerHead : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayerHead instance;
    public SpriteRenderer theSR;
    public Sprite netural, down, up;
    public Sprite current;

    private void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        theSR.sprite = current;
    }

    public void Up()
    {
        current = up;
    }

    public void Down()
    {
        current = down;
    }

    public void Netural()
    {
        current = netural;
    }

}
```

It is importan to use `LateUpdate()` method because the animations are updated between `Update()` and `LateUpdate()`.

Credit goes to DMGregory.